# Why would a new EC2 East instance take me to www.google.com.tw?

Tags: internet-explorer, amazon-ec2, geolocation, international

I set up an EC2 instance in the U.S. East (N. Virginia) region.  It's a Windows Server 2012 instance, and the very first time I visited Google in Internet Explorer, I got redirected to `google.com.tw`.

Why would this be?  I checked the IP address, and it shows up as being in Seattle, WA, so I don't think that Google could be detecting the wrong location.  Could it be that someone had that IP address before me and told Google to take them to the Taiwan page by default?

Edit: I am redirected to the Taiwanese site in Google Chrome as well.

Comment: What's the IP address?

Comment: I'm hesitant to post the whole thing publically, so let's just say 54.x.x.x.  freegeoip.net assures me that it's located in Seattle, WA.